# CodenameOne Charts not rendering well when sharing or simulator screen capture

Tags: codenameone

The recent updates draw the lines on the charts when sharing, but the chart seems to get a bit mangled both when shared and when doing a screen capture on the simulator. The legend gets rotated and moved into the grid area, the title is missing, and there is a yellow outline that runs through the grid area. 
[Different chart renderings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlikD.jpg). The far right image got mirrored somehow when I pasted it, it isn't actually a mirror-image when shared.

Here is a test case:

```
package com.fastlaneinnovations.chartexample;

import com.codename1.charts.ChartComponent;
import com.codename1.charts.models.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import com.codename1.charts.models.XYSeries;
import com.codename1.charts.renderers.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import com.codename1.charts.renderers.XYSeriesRenderer;
import com.codename1.charts.util.ColorUtil;
import com.codename1.charts.views.LineChart;
import com.codename1.components.ShareButton;
import com.codename1.io.FileSystemStorage;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Image;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionListener;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.ImageIO;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Set;

public class ChartExample {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer chartRenderer;
    private Container rpmChartContainer;
    private XYSeries series;
    private LineChart lineChart;
    private ChartComponent chart;
    private Hashtable<Long, Integer> chartData;
    private String chartName = "Chart";
    private String path;
    private Object os;
    private int chartHeight;
    private int chartWidth;
    private ShareButton share;
    private Set<Long> keys;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form form = new Form();
        form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        chartData = new Hashtable<Long, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i += 100) {
            chartData.put(Long.valueOf(i), Integer.valueOf(i));
        }
        rpmChartContainer = new Container();
        rpmChartContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        series = new XYSeries("RPM");
        chartRenderer = createChartRenderer();
        setChartSettings(chartRenderer, "RPM vs Time", "Time (s)", "RPM", 0.0,
                10.0, 0.0, 8000.0, ColorUtil.YELLOW, ColorUtil.WHITE);
        lineChart = new LineChart(buildDataSet(series), chartRenderer);
        chart = new ChartComponent(lineChart);
        chart.setUIID("ChartComponent");
        rpmChartContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, chart);
        updateChart();
        share = new ShareButton();
        share.setName(chartName);
        share.setText("Share this chart");
        share.setTextToShare("RPM chart created by R-P-M Control Center app");
        rpmChartContainer.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, share);
        form.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, rpmChartContainer);
        form.show();
        createShareButton();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void updateChart() {
        keys = chartData.keySet();
        series.clear();
        for (Long key : keys) {
            series.add((key / 1000.0), (chartData.get(key) / 1.0));
        }

    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer createChartRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setPointSize(3f);
        XYSeriesRenderer seriesRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        seriesRenderer.setColor(ColorUtil.GREEN);
        // seriesRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        // seriesRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
        seriesRenderer.setLineWidth(5f);
         seriesRenderer.setShowLegendItem(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(seriesRenderer);
        return renderer;
    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildDataSet(XYSeries dataSeries) {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset multiDataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
        multiDataSet.addSeries(dataSeries);
        return multiDataSet;

    }

    private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer,
            String title, String xTitle, String yTitle, double xMin,
            double xMax, double yMin, double yMax, int axesColor,
            int labelsColor) {
        renderer.setChartTitle(title);
        renderer.setXTitle(xTitle);
        renderer.setYTitle(yTitle);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(xMin);
        // renderer.setXAxisMax(xMax);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(yMin);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax);
        renderer.setAxesColor(axesColor);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(labelsColor);
        renderer.setMarginsColor(ColorUtil.BLACK);
        renderer.setGridColor(ColorUtil.BLACK);
    }

    public void createShareButton() {
        rpmChartContainer.revalidate();
        chartWidth = rpmChartContainer.getWidth();
        chartHeight = rpmChartContainer.getHeight();
        Image chartAsImage = Image.createImage(chartWidth, chartHeight);
        rpmChartContainer.paint(chartAsImage.getGraphics());
        setShareImage(share, chartAsImage);

    }

    public void setShareImage(ShareButton shareButton, Image shareImage) {
        OutputStream os = null;
        final String shareImagePath = FileSystemStorage.getInstance()
                .getAppHomePath() + shareButton.getName();
        FileSystemStorage.getInstance().delete(shareImagePath);
        try {
            os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(
                    shareImagePath);
            ImageIO.getImageIO().save(shareImage, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_JPEG,
                    0.95f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        shareButton.setImageToShare(shareImagePath, "image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In implementing the 2D transformations on iOS mutable images, I fixed some bugs related to transforms on mutable images in the simulator.  You may not have these until the next plugin update.

As for the third image on the right in your screenshot.  What device was that from?  Can you share a test case with your chart so I can test it out?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I added a test case above.

Comment: Also, forgot to add that the device I tested on so far is an iPhone 5s running iOS 9.2. I'll also try it on an Android device this evening if possible.

Comment: Thanks.  I have fixed the issue in iOS.  https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/2513732f1dbf3a39b5c4e52f30837d4441c110fb

For simulator, it was fixed originally, but it takes a little longer to propagate as you need to wait for the libraries to be updated  (I think if you update your libs to the latest it should be there now).

Comment: Thank you, the shared chart picture looks good now. Simulator screen captures are still messed up, but I don't think the updated libraries have made it out yet.